# Unable to locate package when building Docker

Tags: docker

I'm a beginner in using docker and i'm trying to build my own image. 
I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER JC Frane<j.cfrane@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install apache2 -y

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3306
```

Everytime I run `docker build -t koala/lamp .`
It throws an error when getting apache2 saying:

> E: Unable to locate package apache2

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4 - everything builds fine

Comment: I used 17.06.2-ce

Comment: For whoever has the same problem, this has something to do with your network's DNS.